# ArrayList Null Pointer Exception in onPostExecute()

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Getting `NullPointerException` in ArrayList. I'm using the line below to log size of ArrayList but I always get NPE.

What could be the reason?

```
 Log.d("catArrayList:Size:New", ""+categoryArrayList.size());
```

Here is some more code :

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();                 

        Log.d("catArrayList:Size", ""+categoryArrayList.size());
        Log.d("typArrayList:Size", ""+typeArrayList.size());
        Log.d("serArrayList:Size", ""+serviceArrayList.size());

        Log.d("cArrayList:Size", ""+cArrayList.size());
        Log.d("tArrayList:Size", ""+tArrayList.size());
        Log.d("sArrayList:Size", ""+sArrayList.size());

        Category c = categoryArrayList.get(0);      
        typeArrayList = c.getTypeArrayList();
        Log.d("catArrayList:Size:New", ""+categoryArrayList.size());

        for(int i=0;i<typeArrayList.size();i++) {
            tArrayList.add(typeArrayList.get(i).getName());
        }

        spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CategoryActivity.this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                 cArrayList));

        spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CategoryActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                tArrayList));

        spinner3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CategoryActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                sArrayList));

     }
```

**Log** says:

```
 09-12 11:05:54.585: D/catArrayList:Size(30919): 2
09-12 11:05:54.585: D/typArrayList:Size(30919): 2
09-12 11:05:54.585: D/serArrayList:Size(30919): 2
09-12 11:05:54.585: D/cArrayList:Size(30919): 2
09-12 11:05:54.590: D/tArrayList:Size(30919): 2
09-12 11:05:54.590: D/sArrayList:Size(30919): 2
09-12 11:05:54.590: D/AndroidRuntime(30919): Shutting down VM
09-12 11:05:54.590: W/dalvikvm(30919): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f9f2a0)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at com.example.modulewise.CategoryActivity$JSONAsyncTask.onPostExecute(CategoryActivity.java:178)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at com.example.modulewise.CategoryActivity$JSONAsyncTask.onPostExecute(CategoryActivity.java:1)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
09-12 11:05:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(30919):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: At which line getting NPE? which is line number `178` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK at this line : Log.d("catArrayList:Size:New", ""+categoryArrayList.size());  brother

Comment: Because `categoryArrayList` is null. We can't tell why since we don't know where it comes from.

Comment: categoryArrayList is null?

Comment: IMO, you should post body code of getTypeArrayList()

Comment: The method `CategoryActivity.onCreate` is the only place where `categoryArrayList` is initialized. Prior to this, the variable is `null`. So, the conclusons is: If you get a NPE when trying to dereference this variable in another method, the `onCreate` method was _not_ called before. Time to debug, it seems ...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose so finally what would you recommend me ? can you show me the correct way ?

Comment: please initialization  ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList; = new ArrayList<Category>();

Comment: doesnt look like its crashing at that Log . bcoz that log is printing size 2 **09-12 11:05:54.585: D/catArrayList:Size(30919): 2**

Comment: @oreo in this code snippet you didn't add the type array list to your category array list. That's why you get NPE.

Comment: I want to check category class

Comment: `c.getTypeArrayList();` returns NULL. Check it out. @Jolson there is other very similar log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the NPE is thrown on this line:

```
    Log.d("catArrayList:Size:New", ""+categoryArrayList.size());
```

then the reason it is being thrown is that `categoryArrayList` is `null` ... at that point in the program.

Check that that variable is being initialized correctly.

I also strongly suspect that the code that you are running is different to what you have shown us in the question.  By my reading, it is impossible for `categoryArrayList` to be `null` at that point.  If it was, then an NPE would have been thrown two lines previously at:

```
    Category c = categoryArrayList.get(0);
```

Actually, if the application is multi-threaded, and another thread updates `categoryArrayList` in parallel with this thread running this method, then the variable could become null due to a race-condition.  However, I would expect that this would only happen very occasionally.

I guess, another possibility is that the `c.getTypeArrayList()` call is updating `categoryArrayList` as a side-effect.

And a third possibility is that the NPE *doesn't* occur at the line you said.